# jQuery Toggle Width Logic

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying get expanding/ collapsing tabs on click so it's easy for the user to see which tab they're currently on.

I think what I want to do is to traverse through `<div class="sidebar">` 's children and check each one for `.hasClass('clicked')`.
During my traversal, if I find a child that has the class `.clicked`, I want to stop there, `.removeClass()` and `.addClass('clicked')` to whichever tab was originally clicked.

I'm not sure how to do this or if this is even the right way to approach at all.

```js
$(".sidebar a").on('click', function() {
        
        /*if( $(".sidebar").children().hasClass('clicked') ){
            $(this).removeClass('clicked');
        }*/
        
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
```

```css
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 14.5%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    z-index: 500;
}

.sidebar a {
    color: whitesmoke;
    background-color: #404040;
    padding: 26% 20% 26% 15% ;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 800;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 80%;
}

.item {
  display: block;
 }

.sidebar a.clicked {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sidebar">

  <a href="#" class="item"> Item 1 </a>
  <a href="#" class="item"> Item 2 </a>
  <a href="#" class="item"> Item 3 </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the class to the clicked sidebar item and then remove it from [all its siblings]https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) in one go, like so:

```
$(".sidebar").on("click", ".item", function() {
    $(this).addClass("clicked").siblings(".item").removeClass("clicked");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Both of these solutions work, but would you say one is better practice over the other? Or does it not really matter?

Comment: They pretty much do the same thing. I prefer my answer, but that does not mean it is better than the other one ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to just remove it without the test.  This seems to do what you are looking for.

```js
$(".sidebar a").on('click', function() {
  $(".sidebar").children().removeClass('clicked');
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 14.5%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  z-index: 500;
}
.sidebar a {
  color: whitesmoke;
  background-color: #404040;
  padding: 26% 20% 26% 15%;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 800;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 80%;
}
.item {
  display: block;
}
.sidebar a.clicked {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sidebar">

  <a href="#" class="item"> Item 1 </a>
  <a href="#" class="item"> Item 2 </a>
  <a href="#" class="item"> Item 3 </a>

</div>
```